# logging a global variable using var vs let yields different results

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, google-chrome-devtools

In the provided code, I get different `console.log()` statements in VSCode than in Chrome console. As the code is now, when I run this in VSCode the output is `undefined`, however when I run this code in the Chrome console the output is `Nimit Maru`.
If I change the `var` keyword in line 1 to `let` (or `const`), I get `undefined` in both VSCode *and* Chrome console.
Finally, if I remove the `var`/`let` keywords completely, and run line 1 with `fullName = 'Nimit Maru';` my output in both VSCode and Chrome console is `Nimit Maru`.

I understand that the `let` keyword is typically better for local scope, and the `var` keyword will hoist to global scope, but I don't think that explains why I'm getting different results from one console to the next. Seeing as this variable is being defined in the global scope I wouldn't think that would make a difference here.

```
var fullName = 'Nimit Maru';

let myObj = {
  fullName: 'David Yang',
  property: {
    fullName: 'Omri Bernstein',
    getFullName: function() {
      console.log(this.fullName);
    },
  },
};

let whosName = myObj.property.getFullName;

whosName();
```

[image]

Thank you for any insight provided.

Comment: `the var keyword will hoist to global scope` that sentence is not correct because it's talking about two different concepts as if they are related. More specifically *hoisting* does not change scopes - it merely means that the declaration would be processed as if it's further up *in the same scope*.

Comment: `As the code is now, when I run this in VSCode` I've been thinking about this and initially I thought you meant "when I run the code I have written in VSCode as part of an application" but now I relise you might mean there is some REPL tool that VSCode provides, similar to the console. Is that correct? If so, be ware that it might be running your code *differently* - it could very well be wrapping it inside a function, in which case the behaviour you see is the expected one. I think Firebug did that in the past, which meant that code written in it and somewhere else could be slightly different

Comment: Sorry for lack of clarification. I am simply executing this snippet of code inside of VSCode's Terminal using Node.js. I think you are on to something.. I understand the global scope is vastly different from inside of Node.js (in VSCode) than inside Chrome's window object. So I believe you are correct, this snippet is probably be wrapped at the time of invocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var` variables on the top level get automatically assigned to properties of the `window` object. This behavior does not occur for `let` and `const` variables:

```js
var varName = 'foo';
let letName = 'bar';
const constName = 'baz';
console.log(
  window.varName,
  window.letName,
  window.constName
);
```

When you invoke `whosName();`, you invoke it with no calling context, so `this` defaults to `window`. Thus, `this.fullName` inside the function will refer to `window.fullName`, which will only be defined if you used `var fullName`. (If you had used `let fullName` or `const fullName`, it would not have been assigned to `window`, resulting in `undefined`.)

If you wanted to refer to the `fullName` *property* of the inner object (`Omri Bernstein`), use `bind` or another function that calls `myObj.property.getFullName` with the proper calling context:

```js
let myObj = {
  fullName: 'David Yang',
  property: {
    fullName: 'Omri Bernstein',
    getFullName: function() {
      console.log(this.fullName);
    },
  },
};

let whosName1 = () => myObj.property.getFullName();
let whosName2 = myObj.property.getFullName.bind(myObj.property);

whosName1();
whosName2();
```

> I understand that the let keyword is typically better for local scope, and the var keyword will hoist to global scope

This is not correct. `var` has *function* scope and is hoisted, while `const` and `let` have *block* scope. A variable declared with `var` will be scoped to its nearest surrounding function, or the top level, if there is no function.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you. I'm still curious as to the difference of results I'm getting from VSCode's terminal to Chrome's console. Is this just a difference in how the global object is handled from Node.js to chrome's Window object?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue in a plain JS environment like stack snippet or JSFiddle - I think that VSCode is automatically wrapping your code in an IIFE or something (makes sense, to avoid unnecessary global pollution), thus your `var`s not being assigned to the window.

Comment: To clarify, I am using VSCode and Node.js and just running this snippet of code in the built in terminal, then running the same code in Chrome Console. So I'm starting to understand why there is such a difference as the runtime environment is completely different and handles the 'global scope' differently. Thank you for your input!